# Importar função com php 5.4

Tags: php

Estou utilizando uma API, porem ela foi projetada para funcionar no php 5.6+, mas o meu servidor esta com a versão 5.4, alias, meu servidor não o servidor do cliente e este servidor cliente já tem varias aplicações rodando no 5.4 então seria mais complexo atualizar, já que desconheço estas aplicações e elas são enormes, então estou tentar adaptar esta API para rodar na versão 5.4, estava ocorrendo tudo bem, encontrei varias alternativas ate encontrar isso:

```
use function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\modify_request;
```

Onde ele importa uma função de um determinado arquivo, queria saber se a uma alternativa para importar esta função utilizando o php 5.4.

Comment: Se remover o `function` funciona? já precisa de mais algum trabalho na hora de chamar a função.

Comment: @rray aparentemente funcionou, estou rodando a api e corrigindo os erros que estão aparecendo, tirei o function e não deu erro mais nesta função, muito obrigado! Se no final das modificações rodar eu posto aqui se deu tudo certo!

Comment: Conseguir colocando uma barra na frente, desta forma: \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\modify_request(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `use function` é suportado apenas pelo PHP5.6+, assim como com constantes:

```
use const Foo\Bar\CONSTANT;
```

Agora se tratando das funções em https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/functions.php você pode simplesmente importar o `functions_include.php` e usar a função diretamente `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\modify_request(..., ...);` e não use o `use function`:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

require_once 'vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$request = new Request('GET', 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com');

$request = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\modify_request($request, [ 'set_headers' => [ 'foo' => 'bar' ] ]);
```